# How to generate unordered list with hyphen?

Tags: lists

I need to write a list of hyphen.

Following are subjects in high-school.

```
- Physics
- Chemistry 
- Biology
```

How can i generate such list with hyphen as indicator?

Answer (score 9):

With powerful `enumitem`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label=-]
  \item Physics
  \item Chemistry
  \item Mathematics
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Without any package**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
 \renewcommand\labelitemi{-}
  \item Physics
  \item Chemistry
  \item Mathematics
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

If you want this for all `itemize` environments, put the `\renewcommand\labelitemi{-}` outside (say in preamble).

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[-]
\item test
\item test 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]